# Facebook apprequest blank app page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to send app requests to users.

I set up 'Canvas URL' and 'Secure Canvas URL' (certificate for this page is self-signed) as my site home page.

My js code:

```
function do_facebook_login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.ui({
                method: 'apprequests',
                message: 'message',
                data: '{"inviter_id":"some_text"}'
              }, requestCallback);
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_birthday'});
}
```

User successfully send requests. When invited user clicks on request message - opens page with my 'Secure Canvas URL' but I don't get 'request_ids' (actually I don't get any variables in $_GET array).
Also sometimes I get blank page in iframe (it's happens randomly, can not specify in which cases).

Any idea why this can happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` to get params in canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found what the problem was: one of plugins had this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
    // do something
    // redirect to home page
}
```

and facebook app requests have $_GET['ref']